# Puzzle about TabViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have made an app in which i have 2 tabs.and there are navigation controller in them,
The issue is that once i click on the tab bar and there is navigation bar and the view changes as i drill down.But when i go to the second tab and then come back to the 1st tab then it opens the view which was there previously when i changed the tab.So it retain the view whereas i want that that tab should start up with the same first initial view.

From where we can do this by info.plist or what..>?

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0):

Adopt `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol and implement `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:` method.

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)controller {
    [(UINavigationController *)controller popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    return YES;
}
```

This assumes that all tabs have navigation controllers.

Comment: @user755278 Did this help? Do you need further assistance on this?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how tab view controllers work. You can implement this method in your app delegate (after making it the delegate for the UITabeBarController)....

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

Then call a reset method (or similar) on your view controller to pop back to the root view controller.

This is not how you normally work with UITabBarControllers however....

Answer (score 0):

You can implement

```
- tabBarController:didSelectViewController:
```

in the delegate of the UITabBarController and then call

```
– popToRootViewControllerAnimated:
```

on the UINavigationController